# How to reshape keras mask within custom layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, elmo

Note: I posted about this issue already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075088/how-to-resolve-invalidargumenterror-incompatible-shapes-with-custom-elmo-layer). I'm creating a new question because:
1. I think the issue specifically relates to reshaping my mask within my custom layer, but I'm not sure enough of that to completely ignore the other error I wrote about in the original post.
2. There are many posts about reshaping Keras layers or adding Masking layers, but I couldn't find any about reshaping a mask within a layer, so I hope this post can be useful more generally.

The issue:

I have a custom Keras layer that takes 2D input and returns 3D output (batch_size, max_length, 1024), which is passed on to a BiLSTM followed by a CRF.

The custom Keras layer is copied from [this repository](https://github.com/strongio/keras-elmo/blob/master/Elmo%20Keras.ipynb). The difference is I take the 'elmo' instead of 'default' outputs from the Elmo model, so that the output is 3D as required by the BiLSTM:

`result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                      as_dict=True,
                      signature='default',
                      )['elmo'] # The original code used 'default'`

However the compute_mask function isn't appropriate for my architecture, as it's output is 2D. Thus I get the error:

`InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,47] vs. [32,0]    [[{{node loss/crf_1_loss/mul_6}}]]`

where 32 is batch size and 47 is one less than my specified max_length.

I'm sure I need to reshape the mask, but I couldn't find out anywhere how.

Happy to make a git repo with the whole thing and/or full stack trace if need be.

Custom ELMo Layer:

```
class ElmoEmbeddingLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.dimensions = 1024
        self.trainable = True
        super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.elmo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2', trainable=self.trainable, name="{}_module".format(self.name))
    self.trainable_weights += K.tf.trainable_variables(scope="^{}_module/.*".format(self.name))
    super(ElmoEmbeddingLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        result = self.elmo(K.squeeze(K.cast(x, tf.string), axis=1),
                   as_dict=True, signature='default',)['elmo']
        return result

    # Original compute_mask function. Raises; 
    # InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,47] vs. [32,0]      [[{{node loss/crf_1_loss/mul_6}}]]
     def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
         return K.not_equal(inputs, '__PAD__')

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], 48, self.dimensions
```

The model is built as follows:

```
    def build_model(): # uses crf from keras_contrib
        input = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
        model = ElmoEmbeddingLayer(name='ElmoEmbeddingLayer')(input)
        model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True))(model)
        crf = CRF(num_tags)
        out = crf(model)
        model = Model(input, out)
        model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf_loss, metrics=[crf_accuracy, categorical_accuracy, mean_squared_error])
        model.summary()
        return model
```